# Creating components dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an application where I need to dynamically create elements. 
I'm using the following code in the onCreate () method.

```
TextView product = new TextView (this);
product.setText ("" + pName + ""); 
//Add TextView to LinearLayout 
ll.addView (product);
```

Works fine, the problem is when I turn the phone, the items appear duplicated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use xml layout as well? Post the whole onCreate() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate your phone, it destroys the activity and creates again but it saves everything to resume, `onCreate()` method you create textviews again although they are already in the view.

You should check them before create.

You can do that by checking `savedInstanceState`, if it's not null, that means it's being recreated again.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){
   // create your textviews
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `TextView` programmatically and when you turn the phone, you don't eliminate the object from your layout so you are adding elements in your layout everytime you create the activity. You can control it in your `onDestroy()` method.
I hope it helps.